# Django serializer requiring a dict instead of a model instance

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a really simple serialization in a viewset in django, but my serializer, which should require the instance to be serialized, is requiring a dict.

This is my custom serializer:

```py
class JSONAPIModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('many', False) is True:
            context = kwargs.get('context', {})
            context.update({'is_many': True})
            kwargs.update({'context': context})

        return super().__init__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def format_object(self, instance, attributes: dict, meta = None, relationships = None, links = None, is_many: bool = False) -> dict:
        jsonapi_data = {
            'type': instance.__class__.__name__.lower() if not getattr(self.Meta, 'resource_type', None) else None,
            'id': str(instance.id),
            'attributes': attributes,
        }
        jsonapi_data.update({'relationships': relationships}) if relationships else None
        if is_many:
            jsonapi_data = {
                'data': jsonapi_data
            }
        jsonapi_data.update({'meta': meta}) if meta else None
        jsonapi_data.update({'links': links}) if links else None
        return jsonapi_data

    def get_attrs(self, instance):
        return {}
    
    def get_meta(self, instance):
        return None

    def get_links(self, instance):
        return None

    def get_relationships(self, instance):
        return None

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return self.format_object(
            instance=instance,
            is_many=self.context.get('is_many', False),
            attributes=self.get_attrs(instance),
            meta=self.get_meta(instance),
            relationships=self.get_relationships(instance),
            links=self.get_links(instance)
        )

class AnimeSerializer(JSONAPIModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Anime
        fields = '__all__'
        resource_name = 'anime'

    def get_attrs(self, instance):
        return {
            'titles': {
                'en': instance.title_en,
                'es': instance.title_es,
                'en_jp': instance.title_ro,
                'ja_jp': instance.title_jp
            },
            'titleCanonical': instance.title_canonical,
            'abbreviatedTitles': [i.value for i in instance.titles_abbreviated.all()],
            'otherTitles': [i.value for i in instance.titles_others.all()],
            'description': instance.description,
            'coverImage': {
                'tiny': instance.cover.tiny.url if getattr(instance.cover, 'tiny') is not None else None,
                'small': instance.cover.small.url if getattr(instance.cover, 'small') is not None else None,
                'medium': instance.cover.medium.url if getattr(instance.cover, 'medium') is not None else None,
                'large': instance.cover.large.url if getattr(instance.cover, 'large') is not None else None,
                'xlarge': instance.cover.xlarge.url if getattr(instance.cover, 'xlarge') is not None else None,
            },
            'bannerImage': {
                'tiny': getattr(getattr(instance.banner, 'tiny', None), 'url', None),
                'small': getattr(getattr(instance.banner, 'small', None), 'url', None),
                'medium': getattr(getattr(instance.banner, 'medium', None), 'url', None),
                'large': getattr(getattr(instance.banner, 'large', None), 'url', None),
                'xlarge': getattr(getattr(instance.banner, 'xlarge', None), 'url', None),
            },
            'genres': [i.name for i in instance.genres.all()],
            'demography': instance.demography,
            'ageRating': instance.get_age_rating_display(),
            'showType': instance.get_show_type_display(),
            'rating': instance.rating,
            'broadcasting': {
                'startDate': instance.date_start,
                'endDate': instance.date_start,
                'day': instance.get_broadcasting_day_display(),
                'time': instance.broadcasting_time,
            },
            'status': instance.get_status_display(),
            'duration': _('%(min)s min per ep') % {'min': instance.episode_length} if instance.episode_count != 1 else _('%(min)s min') % {'min': instance.episode_length},
            'nsfw': instance.nsfw,
            'source': instance.get_source_display(),
        }

    def get_links(self, instance):
        return {
            "self": "https://api.anibase.co/v1/anime/%s" % instance.id
        }

    def get_relationships(self, instance):
        return {
            "characters": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "https://api.anibase.co/v1/anime/%s/relationships/characters" % instance.id,
                    "self": "https://api.anibase.co/v1/anime/%s/characters" % instance.id
                },
                "data": [{'type': 'character', 'id': str(i.character.id), 'meta': { 'role': i.get_character_type_display() }} for i in instance.characters.all()]
            },
            "staff": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "https://api.anibase.co/v1/anime/%s/relationships/staff" % instance.id,
                    "self": "https://api.anibase.co/v1/anime/%s/staff" % instance.id
                },
                "data": [{'type': 'people', 'id': str(i.staff.id), 'meta': { 'roles': [role.name for role in i.roles.all()] }} for i in instance.staff.all()]
            }
        }

    def get_meta(self, instance):
        return {
            'createdAt': instance.created_at,
            'updatedAt': instance.updated_at,
        }
```

And this is my `ViewSet`:

```py
class JSONAPIModelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet, GenericAPIView):
    """
    A viewset designed to implement the JSON:API spec by default.
    """

    serializer_class: serializers.Serializer = None
    filterset_class: django_filters.FilterSet = None
    pagination_class = JSONAPILimitOffsetPagination
    lookup_field = "id"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)


class AnimeViewSet(JSONAPIModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AnimeSerializer
    filterset_class = AnimeFilter
    relationships = ['characters', 'staff']
```

However, whenever I try to make a request to the `retrieve` view, I get the following response:

```json
{
   non_field_errors: [
      "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Anime."
   ]
}
```

I've tried replacing the `self.get_serializer(instance)` with `self.get_serializer(data={})`, but now the instance passed to `to_representation` in the serializer is an instance of itself. I've tried raising errors to see where the code stopped and the exception is raised in the `is_valid()` check. If I do `is_valid(raise_exception=False)`, I get an empty JSON as a response. I even tried to explictly put the `AnimeSerializer` replacing `self.get_serializer()` but it's no use.

How can I get it to accept the instance as an actual data parameter and stop requiring a dict?

Edit: This only happens with the `retrieve` view, works fine with `list` view.

Comment: You should not call `.is_valid()` while passing `instance` to the serializer unless you send both `instance` and `data`.

Comment: @uedemir if I remove the `is_valid()` check I get an error saying it's a requirement to run it before accessing the data